# SDL linear filtering creates color keying fragments

Tags: sdl

I am using `SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_SCALE_QUALITY, "1");`
for linear filtering on my SDL project. However, I noticed that it applies the filtering *before* color keying, thus I get fragments and a turquoise ring around transparent textures (illustrated below) as SDL fails to recognise the turqouise color i use because it mixes with the edge of the texture.

[Original texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiYAq.png) --
[After filtering and color keying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7mQK.png) (the dark blue is the background)

Answer (score 0):

With `SDL_SetColorKey`, you can't have any alpha levels. It's either fully opaque, or fully transparent. Thus, the edges of you arrow can't mix with your color key, or they will be considered as fully opaque.

What I would suggest if you want different alpha levels, is to use `SDL_Image` ([1.2](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release-1.2.html), [2.0](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/)) with `.png` textures.

The code is very straightforward:

```
SDL_Surface *yourSurface = IMG_Load("path/to/image.png");
```

---

Concerning the turquoise artifacts around your image, it's that the SDL miss pixels at the borders to linearly interpolate to a new one.

EDIT: In the case where you do not want any alpha levels: What you can do, if you are using SDL2, is to disable render scale, and before the blit send your full scene to a `SDL_Texture` you will stretch, instead of resizing an `SDL_Surface`.

Comment: You seem to have the opposite idea, I don't want any alpha levels, and I don't want the texture to mix with the color key. The problem is that the filtering mixes the edge of the texture with the color key, creating a color that SDL_SetColorKey can't recognise, thus it stays opaque. I'm also using a renderer instead of surface blitting.

Comment: @DanielWærness Alright, see my edit. You should put a clear question in your own post about what you want to have.